# jQuery Scrolling & Anchor Initial Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I'm using this jQuery code for smooth scrolling:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 110)
        }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I added the -110 offset to properly adjust the initial position and it's working fine, but every time I try to access the anchor from an external link, the page loads with a different offset value. Please check http://www.iscreatividad.com/clientes/msl/servicios.html#serv-planificacion for a clear view of what the issue is. If you click the first icon it automatically adjusts and you'll see the way it should be loading.

Thanks in advance for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the custom scroll event on click of the anchor and not on load so when you load the page with the id, it jumps to the id which is the default behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    scrollToElem(hash);

    $('a.page-scroll').on('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var href = $anchor.attr('href');
        scrollToElem(href);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

var scrollToElem = function (hash) {
    var target = hash;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: ($(hash).offset().top - 110)
    }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, the only thing is that it actually loads in the wrong position and the script then forces it to slide to the right one. So you see when it's looking to compensate the position. But it's still a great solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mr.Bacan Oh can you update your code on the site so that I can look at the issue there?